# Bash string replacment of curly brackets

Tags: bash

I try to replace a string of the form {string} but somehow it is not working.

```
regex='\{\w*\}'
pattern="{test}_test1"
while [[ $pattern =~ $regex ]]; do
    toreplace=${BASH_REMATCH[@]}
    pattern=${pattern/toreplace/replaced}
done
echo $pattern
```

I would except the following output:

```
replaced_test1
```

Comment: Those are "curly brackets". Angle brackets are what is used for HTML/XML.

Comment: \w is not recognized by bash regex

Comment: @Lix updated title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a "$" and qutoes, change it up so it looks more like this:
 `pattern="${pattern/$toreplace/replaced}"`

It'll work just fine, tested on GNU bash, version 3.2.52

Comment: Thanks, also the version from @Nahuel Fouilleil works

    pattern=${pattern/${toreplace}/replaced}

Answer (score 1):

\w is not recognized by bash regex

```
regex='\{[[:alpha:]]*\}'
pattern="{test}_test1"
while [[ $pattern =~ $regex ]]; do
    toreplace=${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
    pattern=${pattern/${toreplace}/replaced}
done
echo $pattern
```